# Entity Framework Code First : How to map flat table to class with nested objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-4.0, entity-framework-4.3

I have the scenario where the data from a single table must be in 2 objects.

```
[Table]
-Field1
-Field2
-Field3
-Field4
```

And the class look like this:

```
[Class1]
-Field1
-Field2
-Class2 object here

[Class2]
-Field3
-Field4
```

I have set in the Class1 the attribute [NotMapped] over the property of the Class2 which contain the field 3 and 4. I also have added the configuration in the Database Context:

```
public class ConfigurationClass1 : EntityTypeConfiguration<Class1> {
    public ConfigurationClass1 () {
        Property(o => o.Class2.Field3).HasColumnName("Field3");
        Property(o => o.Class2.Field4).HasColumnName("Field4");
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I try to use Entity Framework with the Class1 I got :

> The property 'Class2' is not a declared property on type 'Class2'.
>   Verify that the property has not been explicitly excluded from the
>   model by using the Ignore method or NotMappedAttribute data
>   annotation. Make sure that it is a valid primitive property.

How can I use Entity Framework Code First with an Entity that has nested object with all the information in a flat table?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do like this only in case Class2 can be recognized by EF CF as a [Complex type](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/03/28/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-2-complex-types.aspx).

Briefly:

1. Class2 shouldn't contain any references to other EF Entities. Only
   to other Complex types or standard types
2. Class2 can't be generic. in this case as a workaround you can create a non-generic nested class and use it in your Class1.

Comment: Seems like a lot of hassle for what is a simple issue.

Comment: I had completely forget about ComplexType. Once I set it up with ComplexType attribute, everything worked. Thank you. +1 and accepted :)